# How to calculate matrix exponential of a $2\times 2$ matrix with repeated e values

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Specifically, I am trying to calculate the matrix exponential, $e^{At}$, where A = $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\-9 & 5\end{bmatrix}$. I calculated the the E values to be 2 with a multiplicity of 2 but with only one e vector. Since I cannot diagonalize I thought of splitting A into $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-9 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and then $e^{At}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}e^{-t} & 0\\0 & e^{5t}\end{bmatrix}$ + $\begin{bmatrix}cos(t) & sin(t)\\-9sin(t) & cos(t)\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}e^{-t}+cos(t) & sin(t)\\-9sin(t) & e^{5t}+cos(t)\end{bmatrix}$. Is this correct?

Comment: You need a Dunford decomposition of your matrix to compute its exponential.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Dunford decomp

Comment: This means you write it as the sum of a diagonal matrix $D$ and a nilpotent matrix $N$, such that they commute. Then, in the basis where you have this decomposition,  $\exp(D+N)=\exp D\cdot\exp N$, then back to the original basis.

Comment: Alternatively (or perhaps we are referring to the same thing), you can use the [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) to write $A=P(D+N)P^{-1}$ to have similar effect since $e^D$ and $e^N$ are easy to calculate, and you can take a common factor of $P$ on the left and $P^{-1}$ on the right.

Comment: so what i have is correct except that i need to multiply the two matrices?

Comment: @ajs512 the trick of splitting up the exponential (and *multiplying* rather than adding, as you said) only works if the two matrices commute.

Comment: I suggest you split it into the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&2} + \pmatrix{-3&1\\-9&3}
$$

Comment: what does it mean to 'commute'? ok ill try that split

Comment: "$A$ and $B$ commute" means that $AB = BA$.

Comment: What makes my split nice (besides the fact that the matrices commute) is that
$$
\pmatrix{-3&1\\-9&3}^2 = 0
$$
which makes it easy to compute the exponential with the power series.

Comment: Is there any way to calculate two matrices that commute or do i need to guess and check?

Comment: If you only have one eigenvalue $\lambda$ (repeated however many times), you can always make one of the matrices $\lambda I$ ($I$ being the identity matrix).

Comment: This is an instance of the "Dunford decomposition" that others mentioned.

Comment: @Bernard you mean diagonalizable

Comment: I forgot to write $D+N$ *in some basis* – but that was implicit by the end of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

(The variable $t$ went lost in this answer. JMoravitz's answer takes care of everything.)

Your matrix $A$ is similar to its Jordan normal form
$$B:=2I+N, \qquad N=\left[\matrix{0&1\cr 0&0\cr}\right]\ .$$
As $I$ and $N$ commute, and $N^2=0$, one has
$$\exp(B)=e^2 I\cdot \exp(N)=e^2(I+N)=\left[\matrix{e^2&e^2\cr 0&e^2\cr}\right]\ .$$
So what you need is the matrix $P$ converting $A$ to its normal form $B$.

Comment: You miss the variable — it seems to come from  a differentiable system.

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you. After JMoravitz's answer I refrain from updating mine.

Answer (score 1):

We find the Jordan form of the matrix: $A=PJP^{-1}$

$\begin{bmatrix} -1&1\\-9&5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&-\frac{1}{3}\\3&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{3}\\-3&1\end{bmatrix}$

So, $e^{At} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(At)^k$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(P\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]P^{-1}t)^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}P(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]t)^kP^{-1} = P\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]t)^k\right)P^{-1}$

$=P\left(e^{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]t}\right)P^{-1} = P\left(e^{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]t+\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]t}\right)P^{-1}$

$=P\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2t&0\\0&2t\end{smallmatrix}\right]^k\right)\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1t\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]^n\right)P^{-1}$

$=P\begin{bmatrix}e^{2t}&0\\0&e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&1t\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+0+0+\cdots\right)P^{-1}~~~~~(\dagger)$

$=P\begin{bmatrix}e^{2t}&te^{2t}\\0&e^{2t}\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$

$=\begin{bmatrix}e^{2t}-3te^{2t}&te^{2t}\\-9te^{2t}&e^{2t}+3te^{2t}\end{bmatrix}$

Once familiar with the method, one usually skips straight to $(\dagger)$ after finding the Jordan form.

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix+exponential%28%7B%7B-t%2Ct%7D%2C%7B-9t%2C5t%7D%7D%29) returns the same result.